# An other way to manage Django Model instance from ModelChoiceField in formset

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, formsets

I'm not sure if it's possible. I'm trying to use Django (2.0) `Form` and `Formset`
on a view. Here is my models:

```
from uuid import uuid4

class Aliment(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=36, primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    libelle = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.libelle

class Menu(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=36, primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    libelle = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    aliments = models.ManyToManyField(Aliment, through='Ingredient')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.libelle

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=36, primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    aliment = models.ForeignKey(Aliment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantite = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return "({0}:{1})".format(self.quantite, self.aliment)
```

I'm using `Formset` to handle `('aliment', 'quantite')` from `Ingredient`. Here is my forms:

```
class MenuModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ['libelle',]

class IngredientModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = ['aliment', 'quantite',]
```

The main purpose is, `Menu` have several `Aliment` through `Ingredient` class.
With javascript, I dynamically add `Aliment` item from one list (list1) to `Menu.Ingredient` list (list2).

The only way for the user to add item in list2 is by clicking some "add button" of list1.

The problem is `ModelChoiceField` comes with select that contains all `Aliment` instance from database.

I would to manage a kind of tuple `('aliment.id', 'aliment.libelle', 'quantite')` for each `Ingredient`
that belongs to `Menu` instance.

One the one hand, I could be able to display in my `Ingredient formset` template, something like this :

```
<table>
    {% for item in menu.ingredient %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p name="{{ item.aliment.html_name }}" id="{{ fs.aliment.id_for_label }}"
                value="{{ item.aliment.id }}">{{ fs.aliment.libelle }}</p>
            </td>
            <td><input type="number" name="{{ item.quantite.html_name }}" value="{{ item.quantite.value }}" id="{{ item.quantite.id_for_label }}" /></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

On the other hand, what is the way for getting `Aliment` instance of `Ingredient formset` iteration ?

I don't know if Django `Form` and Django philosophy are made for this.

Could you make some suggestions please.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was confused when asking question. I will try to
be more concise next time.

Anyway, I found a solution to many problem (Maybe you will understand what I meant :p).

I added `libelle` field to my `IngredientModelForm` like this :

```
class IngredientModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(kwargs['instance'])
        self.fields['libelle'].initial = kwargs['instance'].aliment.libelle

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = ['aliment', 'quantite',]

    libelle = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
```

So I can access to `libelle` field in my template.
In my view file I did like this :

```
def add_menu(request):
    ingredientFormSet = modelformset_factory(Ingredient, form=IngredientModelForm, fields=('aliment', 'quantite'), extra=0)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MenuForm(request.POST)
        formset = ingredientFormSet(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            ...
    else:
        menu = Menu.objects.all()[0]
        form = MenuModelForm(instance=menu)
        formset = ingredientFormSet(queryset=menu.ingredient_set.all())
```

So for each `IngredientModelForm` instance, its initial value for `libelle` field will be the value
of the `Aliment` instance attached to `Ingredient`.

Let's take a look at template :

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <ul>
        {% for fs in formset.forms %}
        <li>
        {{ fs.id.label_from_instance }}
            <span><input type="hidden" name="{{ fs.id.html_name }}" value="{{ fs.id.value }}" id="{{ fs.id.id_for_label }}" /></span>
            <span><input type="hidden" name="{{ fs.aliment.html_name }}" value="{{ fs.aliment.value }}" id="{{ fs.aliment.id_for_label }}" /></span>
            <span>{{ fs.libelle.value }}<input type="hidden" name="{{ fs.libelle.html_name }}" value="{{ fs.libelle.value }}" id="{{ fs.libelle.id_for_label }}" /></span>
            <span><input type="number" name="{{ fs.quantite.html_name }}" value="{{ fs.quantite.value }}" id="{{ fs.quantite.id_for_label }}" /></span>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Ajouter" />
</form>
```

So, I can display name of `Aliment` with a `select widget` (because my `Aliment` choices are managed with an other list).

I don't know if it's a good practice for Django.

Feel free to suggest an other simple solution ! :)